# How to Convert time to category in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, categorical-data

How to convert time to some category?

For example, times between 17:30:13 and 19:30:13 should be categorized as "in the evening." Times between 12:00:12 and 13:00:12 should fall under "noon."

What is a good approach to do this in python?

Comment: What would you expect when the interval is 12:00:00 to 17:00:00 . Does the lower bound hour ( here 12 ) prioritize category versus the upper bound hour ( 17 )

Comment: @Govardhan Welcome to [so]! Broad questions like this are hard to answer in a way that leaves one best answer. This is probably off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it for machine learning you normally want it to be a integer value, or transform it into a [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) encoding.

To get the integer value you can integer divide on the hour:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

values = [datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(24)] 

[value.hour // 6 for value in values]
```

yields:

```
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use any machine learning library. Wrote a function that returns a category 
depending on what the lower bound hour of the day is.

Based on your example , I'd assume the lower bound hour does prioritize the category.
Maybe I'd like to understand the use case a bit better.

```
# hour can be some number from 0 to 23 which is also the lower bound hour 
# in the mentioned interval 
# 17:30:13- 19:30:13 should fall under "evening"
# 12:00:12-13:00:12  should fall under "noon"
# For 17:30:13- 19:30:13 , hour will be 17
# For 12:00:12-13:00:12 , hour will be 12
get_category(hour):
    if hour < 12:
        return "morning"
    elif hour == 12:
        return "noon"
    elif hour > 12 and hour < 16:
        return "evening"
    else:
        return "night"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to name a function by yourself and customize the cutoff time.

```
import datetime
# test date
Testdate = datetime.datetime.now().time()

def GetDateCate (DateInput):
    # name a cutoff date:
    noon = datetime.time(12) 
    evening =datetime.time(18) 
    if Testdate <noon:
        print('Morning')
    elif Testdate <evening:
        print('Afternoon')
    else: 
        print('Night')

GetDateCate(Testdate)
```